# Rewriting a react-addons feature on React 15.1.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How would I rewrite the following code without using 'LinkedStateMixin'? Since I am upgrading to React 15.0 and this feature is deprecated.

```
reactMixin(LoginView.prototype, React.addons.LinkedStateMixin);


<div className='form-group'>
  <input type='text'
    className='form-control input-lg'
    valueLink={this.linkState('email')}
    placeholder='Email' />
</div>
<div className='form-group'>
  <input type='password'
    className='form-control input-lg'
    valueLink={this.linkState('password')}
    placeholder='Password' />
</div>
```

The above code is where it is being used and I am using Redux for managing state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just manage the state yourself.  Are you using babel/es6?

```
  class MyForm extends React.Component {
    state = {}

    emailChanged = (e) => {
      this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    }

    passwordChanged = (e) => {
      this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
       const { email, password } = this.state;
       return (
         <form>
           <div className='form-group'>
             <input type='text'
               className='form-control input-lg'
               value={email}
               placeholder='Email'
               onChange={this.emailChanged} />
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input type='password'
                className='form-control input-lg'
                value={password}
                placeholder='Password'
                onChange={this.passwordChanged} />
           </div> 
         </form>
       );
    }
 }
```

Example: http://www.webpackbin.com/EJjZTnu4Z

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Two-Way Binding Helpers doc page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-before-and-after), there's an example that shows how to do the same thing without using `LinkedStateMixin`.